# My List(Of PublicCLass) is only filled with last data VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on reading text from a file and sorting the data to give me the last unique entries.
(Microsoft visual studio Version 16.9.3)

I've made a previous question but realise that it was too vague for it to get an answer. Pᴇʜ did help me out with this article: 
[Split and Store a text file into an array using ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25996514/split-and-store-a-text-file-into-an-array-using-arraylist/25996851#25996851)

**I've tried to modify it but the sorting/order does not work, probably because each index value of my List(Of PublicCLass) is filled with only the latest data. Does anybody know why only the last data is saved inside the List(Of PublicClass)? I cannot see the mistake I made (nevertheless i will continue searching for it)**

Input looks like this (length is unknown):

```
[MACHINE]LBL;[PROG]1;[DATE]2015114_113853;[TYPE]UINT;[ID]1;[OLD_VALUE]99;[NEW_VALUE]1;
[MACHINE]LBL;[PROG]1;[DATE]2015114_113948;[TYPE]UINT;[ID]1;[OLD_VALUE]1;[NEW_VALUE]99;
[MACHINE]DBX;[PROG]4;[DATE]2021310_113527;[TYPE]TIME;[ID]25;[OLD_VALUE]100000000;[NEW_VALUE]50000000;
[MACHINE]LBL;[PROG]5;[DATE]2021310_14264;[TYPE]TRIGGER;[ID]3;[OLD_VALUE_1]330;[NEW_VALUE_1]325;[OLD_VALUE_2]0;[NEW_VALUE_2]0;[OLD_VALUE_3]0;[NEW_VALUE_2]0;
```

My code:

```
        Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click

        Dim sr As New StringReader(TextUpload)
        Dim DataList = New List(Of DataEntry)()
        Dim srline As String
        Dim line = New List(Of String)
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim d = New DataEntry()
        Dim DataListList = New List(Of List(Of DataEntry))
        Do While sr.Peek() >= 0

            srline = sr.ReadLine
            line.Add(srline)
            'MsgBox(srline)
            Data = srline.Split(New String() {";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

            If Data.Length < 9 Then
                With d
                    .DataMachine = Data(0)
                    .DataProg = Data(1)
                    .DataDate = Mid(Data(2).Split("_").First, 7)
                    .DataType = Data(3)
                    .DataID = Data(4)
                    .DataOldValue1 = Data(5)
                    .DataNewValue1 = Data(6)
                End With
            Else
                If Data.Length = 9 Then
                    With d
                        .DataMachine = Data(0)
                        .DataProg = Data(1)
                        .DataDate = Data(2)
                        .DataType = Data(3)
                        .DataID = Data(4)
                        .DataOldValue1 = Data(5)
                        .DataNewValue1 = Data(6)
                        .DataOldValue2 = Data(7)
                        .DataNewValue2 = Data(8)
                    End With
                End If
            End If

            DataList.Add(d)
            DataListList.Add(DataList)

            i = i + 1
            If (i = line.Count) Then
                i = line.Count - 1
            End If
        Loop
        Dim sorted = DataList.OrderBy(Function(y) y.DataDate).ToList
        MsgBox("Lengte line= " & line.Count & vbCrLf & "Datalistcount= " & DataList.Count & vbCrLf & line(0) & vbCrLf
               )
        'MsgBox("Lengte line= " & line.Count & vbCrLf & "i=" & i)
    End Sub
End Class




Public Class DataEntry
    Public DataMachine As String
    Public DataProg As String
    Public DataDate As Integer
    Public DataType As String
    Public DataID As String
    Public DataOldValue1 As String
    Public DataNewValue1 As String
    Public DataOldValue2 As String
    Public DataNewValue2 As String
End Class
```

Comment: Move line `Dim d = New DataEntry()` inside the loop. Having it outside will update single instance of `DataEntry` with different values, that why you see that list contains only entry of last row.

Comment: @Fabio Thank you, this has solved the issue.